# Angular router with multiple views

Tags: angular, angular-routing

**Is there any way how I can render two components of the same level for the same route?**

router config(part of it)

```
const routing: Routes = [
{
    path: 'base',
    component: ParentComponent,
    children: [
        {path: '', redirectTo: 'route1'},
        {path: 'route1', children: [
            {path: '', component: Route1Component1, outlet: 'outlet1'},
            {path: '', component: Route1Component2, outlet: 'outlet2'}]},
        {path: 'route2', children: [
            {path: '', component: Route2Component1, outlet: 'outlet1'},
            {path: '', component: Route2Component2, outlet: 'outlet2'}]}
    ]
}];
```

here is html where i want it to be rendered:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <router-outlet name="outlet1"></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <div>
        <router-outlet name="outlet2"></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not sure if you can do that, but what I'm sure you can do it's to have a wrapper component and make it stateful and then render as many as you want inside as stateless. Does it make sense?

Comment: @AlejandroLora, It does, but I this case I'll have some duplicated html logic in wrapper elements. It's not the ideal solution for me, but if there is no way to do what i want to, I will have to implement wrapper solution

Comment: Well I don't know ur case but it doesn't sound for me as the best approach, cause imagine you need some logical, data to retrieve or theming/customization for those components, which is kind of normal if the app grows, how do you pretend to have that logic in place by that routing code sample above? however, with the approach I told you, you have a stateful component which has the power of retrieving data/customize or do some logic, and the only code you'll have to duplicate is the name of the component in the Html, which for me, it's an assumable cost, just my opinion, not sure about ur case